# How do I get rid of chrome autofill suggestions so they don’t appear?

Tags: google-chrome, browser, history

When I clear history, I have the option to clear:

- browsing history
- download history
- cookies and other site data
- cached images and files
- passwords and other sign-in data
- autofill form data
- site settings
- hosted app data

I have cleared all of these from the beginning of time ("all time" option) and url suggestions from past history still show up. I have also tried the following:

- disabling omnibox autofill settings
- highlighting the url and pressing ctrl+shift+del, shift+del, and fn+shift+del (I'm on windows)
- clicking the 'x' next to the suggestion
- clearing all bookmarks

The only way to get rid of the autofill url from websites visited in the past is to uninstall and reinstall Chrome without saving browsing data. Not only is this annoying, it's also not a long-term fix since chrome starts saving urls again within 3 days.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Some website auto fill is facilitated by the website, so I do not think you can eliminate all of it. This kind of auto fill has been around for years.